# ubuntu suspend works, but then immediately starts

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

Having a strange problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04. Previously I could suspend just fine, the computer will switch itself off. Pressing the ON button will switch it on and it will resume.

After upgrading to 12.04 however, when I suspend it does (almost) the same, turns itself off, but about 2 seconds later, the computer turns itself on again, and it goes back to life from suspend.

I haven't changed any of the hardware or BIOS and it was working before just fine. Also tried every possible switch of `pm-suspend` ; setting `acpi_sleep=nonvs` in `/etc/default/grub` and also [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/139802/73080) but nothing seems to make a difference...

UPDATE: just tested suspend using the 12.04 liveCD and it was working perfectly fine... but when I boot normally it doesn't.

ANOTHER UPDATE: After re-installing I noticed that I can suspend. However, after restoring my home folder - the strange suspend problem happens again. I then created a new user account. When I login to the other account I can suspend without a problem... So **This seems specific to my account only**. How/What can cause this in my own user settings?

Comment: This should be on AskUbuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cleaning my `.config` folder and starting with a fresh config seems to have solved this... however **only temporarily**. After a while the problem started happening again.

I've [moved this question to AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/158532/73080) in hope to figure out what specific configuration is causing this.